# Simple form always inserting \' once typed '

Tags: forms, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

have this crazy issue with string escaping, if I insert ' in to fields I am getting \' in return, I am not even escaping any string? Could you tell me what happen and how do I display ' correctly ?

```
<?php echo $_POST['auction_title']; ?>


<form action="dummy.php" method="post">

<input name="auction_title" id="auction_title">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Guessing: I think you have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) on. What language are your code in?

Comment: @luiges90 he is using php.... <?php echo $_POST['auction_title']; ?>

Comment: it's php, just checking php.ini for that

Comment: all sorted, thanks guys :) magic_quotes_gpc = off
magic_quotes_runtime = off
magic_quotes_sybase = off